# msaccess application crash when network down

Tags: ms-access, sql-server-express

I have an Access application with a timer on a form to refresh data from SQL express database tables linked in the Access database.

The form is like a dashboard displaying the counts of records in tables.  The Access application and the SQL server database is on the same laptop.

The application works well when the internet connection is stable.  If however I move my laptop from my home to another location, the application crashes (loses SQL server connection) and I need to close and open it again to work.

I suspect it has something to do with the firewall settings or network configuration that causes the problem.

Any ideas?  Thanks

Comment: How are you connecting to the SQL server?

Comment: My Access database does not host the tables.  The tables in Access are linked SQL server tables

Comment: Yes, but how is the connection formed? What's the connection string?

Comment: I used the Access external database connection to link them.  Access 2016

Comment: Using a wizard is no insurance for the connection string being correct, and excuse for not knowing the connection string. Note that this is a site for  enthusiast and professional programmers, some knowledge is expected.

Comment: I am sorry to not have the knowledge you expected.  I am an enthusiast programmer.  Have done many access applications.  Will try and become more knowledgeable before asking something here again.  So reading it will be rather than asking.

Comment: Well, you can print out the connection string by executing `?CurrentDb.TableDefs("myTableName").Connect` in the immediate window. However, if you've used the wizard, you're likely using a DSN. [DSN-less connections](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/892490/how-to-create-a-dsn-less-connection-to-sql-server-for-linked-tables-in) are often preferred and easier to troubleshoot.

Comment: Thank you for your help.